# How to remove anacnda environments that's not in default env directories?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I created an conda environment in the path of my choice rather than anaconda's default directory with:

`~$ conda create --prefix=/data/sfy_envs/test python=3.8`

After successed, the environments are visible in conda:

```
~$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /data/miniconda3
maskrcnn_sfy             /data/miniconda3/envs/maskrcnn_sfy
torch16-sfy              /data/miniconda3/envs/torch16-sfy
                         /data/sfy_envs/test
                         /data/sfy_envs/tf2-sfy
```

The last two environments are created with `--prefix` parameters, and have no name. I can activate them by directly refer to their path:

`~$ conda activate /data/sfy_envs/test`

But I cannot remove them. For example to remove `test`, I tried:

```
~$ conda remove /data/sfy_envs/test
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - /data/sfy_envs/test
```

and

```
~$ conda remove -p /data/sfy_envs/test

CondaValueError: no package names supplied,
       try "conda remove -h" for more details
```

These won't work and I have on idea why.

Or could I just delete the environment directory manually, and remove their paths from the file `.conda/environments.txt`? I'm not sure if it's a safe treatment.

Comment: Can you try something like `conda /data/sfy_envs/test remove`?

Comment: @newbie99 I tried. But it's an invalid command. ```~$ conda /data/sfy_envs/test remove
usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...
conda: error: argument command: invalid choice: '/data/sfy_envs/test' (choose from 'clean', 'config', 'create', 'help', 'info', 'init', 'install', 'list', 'package', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'run', 'search', 'update', 'upgrade')```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
conda env remove --prefix /data/sfy_envs/test
```

or

```
conda remove --prefix /data/sfy_envs/test --all
```